# Support needs to do the SPI communication with ASR6601 microcontroller using external sensor

Tags: c, embedded, spi, serial-communication

Currently, I am exploring the ASR6601 microcontroller which is a general LPWAN Wireless Communication SoC.
In that, I am specifically working on SPI & I2S external sensors integration with the AS6601SE controller.

For SPI/ SSP,
I tried to explore using the asr_lora_6601-master base examples which were given in the git hub. As per my understanding, it is transmitting the data to the SSPx Data register, and receiving the same data from the Data register of SPI which was sent during the transmission.
By using that as a reference, I tried to integrate the ADX345 sensor with the AS6601SE controller, but I couldn't establish proper communication with the slave (ADXL345 sensor).
I am getting the constant value for all the Rx buffers while reading the sis continuous register. I have attached the output screenshot in attachment. Kindly go through it once.
I have integrated the same ADXL345 sensor with the other controllers like STM32 & RAK. In that, I am getting the proper output for SPI integration using the HAL drivers.
But here all are based on the tremo drivers, Which is a little difficult compared to the HAL library.

Hope for your positive reply! If possible kindly help me by sharing the application-related SPI integration code with ASR6601SE using external sensors.

I have attached the code lines which was done in main file. Kindly correct if anything I did wrong in this.
ADXL345 integration with ASR6601SE Source code. I didn't use any interrupt method here. I am just using the continuous polling read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tremo_regs.h"
#include "tremo_rcc.h"
#include "tremo_spi.h"
#include "tremo_gpio.h"
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "tremo_uart.h"
#include "tremo_delay.h"

#define SPI_X     SSP1


void uart_log_init(void);

void SPITransf(uint8_t addr, uint8_t data);
void SPIReceive(uint8_t addr, uint8_t size);

uint8_t spi1_rx_data[6] = {0};


void spi0_tx_rx(void)
{
  rcc_enable_peripheral_clk(RCC_PERIPHERAL_SSP1, true);


  ssp_init_t init_struct;

  ssp_init_struct(&init_struct);

  ssp_init(SPI_X, &init_struct);

  ssp_cmd(SPI_X, ENABLE);

  SPITransf(0x2D, 0);    // For reseting power control register in slave's power control register
  delay_ms(100);
  SPITransf(0x2D, 8);    // For setting the measurement mode in slave's power control register
  delay_ms(100);
  SPITransf(0x31, 1);    // For setting range as +/- 4g in slave's data format register
  delay_ms(100);
}

int main(void)
{
  rcc_enable_peripheral_clk(RCC_PERIPHERAL_GPIOB, true);
  rcc_enable_peripheral_clk(RCC_PERIPHERAL_UART0, true);
  uart_log_init();

  gpio_init(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP_HIGH);
  gpio_write(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_LEVEL_HIGH);

  gpio_set_iomux(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, 4);  // CLK:GP24
  //gpio_set_iomux(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, 4);  // NSS:GP25
  gpio_set_iomux(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_10, 4); // TX:GP26
  gpio_set_iomux(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_11, 4); // RX:GP27

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1) {
    spi0_tx_rx();   // for initializing the SPI
    delay_us(20);
    gpio_write(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_LEVEL_LOW);
    delay_us(20);
    SPIReceive(0x32, 6);      // For reading the continuous 6 data register from ADXL slave
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      printf("ssp_Receive_data[%d], 0x%x\r\n", i, spi1_rx_data[i]);
    }

    delay_us(20);
    ssp_cmd(SPI_X, DISABLE);
    ssp_deinit(SPI_X);        // for De-initializing the SPI
    delay_ms(5000);
  }
}


void uart_log_init(void)
{
  // uart0
  gpio_set_iomux(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0, 1);  // UART0  Tx
  gpio_set_iomux(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1, 1);  // UART0  Rx

  /* uart config struct init */
  uart_config_t uart_config;
  uart_config_init(&uart_config);

  uart_config.baudrate = UART_BAUDRATE_115200;

  uart_init(UART0, &uart_config);  // CONFIG_DEBUG_UART = UART0
  uart_cmd(UART0, ENABLE);
}
void SPITransf(uint8_t addr, uint8_t data)
{
  uint8_t txarr[2] = {0};
  addr |= 0x40;  // multibyte read
  txarr[0] = addr;
  txarr[1] = data;
  gpio_write(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_LEVEL_LOW);
  delay_us(20);
  ssp_send_data(SPI_X, txarr , sizeof (txarr));
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (txarr); i++) {
    printf("SendData[%d], 0x%x\r\n", i, txarr[i]);
  }
  gpio_write(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_LEVEL_HIGH);
}

void  SPIReceive(uint8_t addr, uint8_t size )
{
  uint8_t  rxarr[1] = {0};
  addr |= 0x80;  // read operation
  addr |= 0x40;  // multibyte read
  rxarr[0] = addr;
  gpio_write(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_LEVEL_LOW);
  delay_us(20);
  ssp_send_data(SPI_X, rxarr , 1);
  ssp_receive_data(SPI_X, spi1_rx_data , size);
  gpio_write(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_LEVEL_HIGH);
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT
void assert_failed(void* file, uint32_t line)
{
  (void)file;
  (void)line;

  while (1) { }
}
#endif
```

Output: Text

```
[21:34:28.982] SendData[0], 0x6d
SendData[1], 0x0
[21:34:29.094] SendData[0], 0x6d
SendData[1], 0x8
[21:34:29.189] SendData[0], 0x71
SendData[1], 0x1
[21:34:29.313] ssp_Receive_data[0], 0xc1
ssp_Receive_data[1], 0xc1
ssp_Receive_data[2], 0xc1
ssp_Receive_data[3], 0xc1
ssp_Receive_data[4], 0xc1
ssp_Receive_data[5], 0xc1
[21:34:34.323] SendData[0], 0x6d
SendData[1], 0x0
[21:34:34.435] SendData[0], 0x6d
SendData[1], 0x8
[21:34:34.530] SendData[0], 0x71
SendData[1], 0x1
[21:34:34.654] ssp_Receive_data[0], 0xfd
ssp_Receive_data[1], 0xfd
ssp_Receive_data[2], 0xfd
ssp_Receive_data[3], 0xfd
ssp_Receive_data[4], 0xfd
ssp_Receive_data[5], 0xfd
[21:34:39.666] SendData[0], 0x6d
SendData[1], 0x0
[21:34:39.777] SendData[0], 0x6d
SendData[1], 0x8
[21:34:39.872] SendData[0], 0x71
SendData[1], 0x1
[21:34:39.997] ssp_Receive_data[0], 0xfd
ssp_Receive_data[1], 0xfd
ssp_Receive_data[2], 0xfd
ssp_Receive_data[3], 0xfd
ssp_Receive_data[4], 0xfd
ssp_Receive_data[5], 0xfd
[21:34:45.009] SendData[0], 0x6d
SendData[1], 0x0
[21:34:45.104] SendData[0], 0x6d
SendData[1], 0x8
[21:34:45.216] SendData[0], 0x71
SendData[1], 0x1
[21:34:45.312] ssp_Receive_data[0], 0x2
ssp_Receive_data[1], 0x2
ssp_Receive_data[2], 0x2
ssp_Receive_data[3], 0x2
ssp_Receive_data[4], 0x2
ssp_Receive_data[5], 0x2
[21:34:50.351] SendData[0], 0x6d
SendData[1], 0x0
[21:34:50.448] SendData[0], 0x6d
SendData[1], 0x8
[21:34:50.559] SendData[0], 0x71
SendData[1], 0x1
[21:34:50.656] ssp_Receive_data[0], 0xfa
ssp_Receive_data[1], 0xfa
ssp_Receive_data[2], 0xfa
ssp_Receive_data[3], 0xfa
ssp_Receive_data[4], 0xfa
ssp_Receive_data[5], 0xfa
[21:34:55.687] SendData[0], 0x6d
SendData[1], 0x0
[21:34:55.798] SendData[0], 0x6d
SendData[1], 0x8
[21:34:55.894] SendData[0], 0x71
SendData[1], 0x1
[21:34:56.019] ssp_Receive_data[0], 0x1c
ssp_Receive_data[1], 0x1c
ssp_Receive_data[2], 0x1c
ssp_Receive_data[3], 0x1c
ssp_Receive_data[4], 0x1c
ssp_Receive_data[5], 0x1c
[21:35:01.029] SendData[0], 0x6d
SendData[1], 0x0
[21:35:01.140] SendData[0], 0x6d
SendData[1], 0x8
[21:35:01.236] SendData[0], 0x71
SendData[1], 0x1
[21:35:01.360] ssp_Receive_data[0], 0x11
ssp_Receive_data[1], 0x11
ssp_Receive_data[2], 0x11
ssp_Receive_data[3], 0x11
ssp_Receive_data[4], 0x11
ssp_Receive_data[5], 0x11
```

Correct me, If I did anything wrong in mentioned code.
I have attached the output screenshot of the Shared code.
If possible kindly help me by sharing the application-related SPI integration code with ASR6601SE using external sensors.

Comment: Screenshots, where? BTW, please do _not_ add screenshots, if they show text. Copy the text verbatim. -- Please indent your source properly, it is hard to read. -- In `SPITransf()` and `SPIReceive()`, why are you waiting for `SPI_X->SR & 0x100` _after_ deselecting the device?

Comment: That is added only for my verification to know the bus status. But it didn't make any sense to me. My code didn't get stuck by adding that.  Initially, I tested it without adding that condition. But same thing is observed as a output.  And also I have attached the missed output image now.

Comment: Thanks for the output, but would you mind to replace the screenshot by text? I'm sure that you can copy and paste the output.

Comment: Done as you said! And, Is there any solution for the raised query from your side?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `gpio_set_iomux()` call missing for pin GP25?

```
//gpio_set_iomux(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, 4);  // NSS:GP25
```

If you want to control GP25 pin programmatically you should initialize it as the following:

`gpio_set_iomux(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, 0);  // 0 -> fun=0, See Ai-ThinkerRa-08 GPIO`

Function MUX Table document.